# Docker giving the error "Invalid container: [container id]"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, amazon-web-services

I'm running an AWS instance that is running docker containers. I accidentally unmounted one of them, but I got it remounted. Since remounting, I haven't been able to enter any of the containers. I'm running the command `docker exec -it [container id] sh` which is the command I've always used and has always worked, but since remounting I get the error `invalid container: [container id]` on every container. I'm copying the container id's directly from the results of the command `docker ps`.
I've done some searching but the only results I'm getting have to do with the error `invalid docker name`, which isn't quite the same. Thank you in advance for your help and please let me know if you need any more information.